# Rails - AJAX PUT or PATCH firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ajax

I'm trying to update a resource's attribute via AJAX (using `PUT` or `PATCH` request) and the request is getting fired multiple times.

I'm using Angular JS and jQuery.

### HTML Template

Here is how my HTML Template looks like -

```
<span id="test" ng-click="setValue('test')"></span>
```

### Javascript Code

Here is how my Angular JS code looks like -

```
$scope.setValue = function(value){
    $.ajax({
       method: 'PATCH' // or PUT,
       url: 'resources/' + $scope.resourceId,
       data: {
          test: value
       }
    }).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

### Rails Code

Here is how my controller's update method looks like -

```
def update
   @resource.update(resource_params)
   respond_with(@resource)
end
```

### Screenshots

The AJAX request gets fired several times (close to 15 times). See screenshot below -

[image]

By simply changing the `PATCH` (or `PUT`) request to `POST`, the call gets fired only one. See screenshot below -

[image]

Is there any reason why the `PUT` requests are getting fired multiple times, while the `POST` request gets fired only once?

Even though the `PUT` request updates the value correctly. I'd like to prevent it from being fired multiple times. Is there any way to do that? (Without changing the routes or controller methods)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note: your screenshot from your POST request is returning 404, most likely because you're not updating your controller action to be a `create` instead of an `update. (Make sure that your routes are set up to match as well). Since there's no action, Rails returns a 404, and it will stop processing.

This is important, because your PATCH screenshot looks like it's probably infinitely redirecting to itself. Each PATCH request is getting an HTTP 302 Redirect in response, and since you're getting a lot of them, my guess is that it's redirecting to itself (either the same URL, or a URL that redirects to the same controller method... or some other middleware that's causing a redirect for any URL).

So, if you changed your controller action and route to allow for a POST, I bet you'd get the same multiple requests & redirects that you get with a PATCH.

That solves the one mystery. The next is to ask why you're getting the infinite redirects. I can't answer that from the available information, but this might get you started on a solution.